# When to sit down when davening

Tags: tefilla, tzibur-community, standing-sitting

During Shabbat morning davening, we recite Psalm 136 and my siddur has the following instruction, "Most congregations recite the following psalm while standing". So I make sure to stand and then begin to recite it.

However, I am not sure if the practice of standing remains only until I, as an individual, am done saying that section or if I should wait until the person leading the davening says the last line(s) indicating that the congregation as a whole is moving on to the next paragraph of prayer.

In my synagogue I see some people sit down as soon as they are done and wait, while others stay standing and wait to sit until the leader finishes.

Does the obligation to stand end when I finish the last word or when the congregation moves on? Someone davening alone would not have this tension between his private reading speed and the communal progress.

[I know that this same issue arises for other parts of davening so would any answer be local to this prayer, or generalizable to other cases, such as rising for parts of Kabbalat Shabbat?]

Comment: I don't think there is a halachic concept of Psukei Dizimra Betzibbur. If your custom is to stand for that paragraph do so. No need to give any attention to the Chazzan during PdZ at all. Some places don't even have one.

Comment: @DoubleAA Does the presence of kaddish before Baruch She'amar speak to a difference between it said as a tzibbur and it said alone? And what about Kabbalat Shabbat?

Comment: All those are really, really late additions to the Siddur. Siddurim not 200 years ago didn't always include Mizmor Shir before Baruch SheAmar. Public study gets a Kaddish, but not because it's part of Davening; Kaddish after RYishmael is just like Kaddish after a Shiur. Public Davening starts at (or [subsequent to](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56277/759)) Yishtabach, and goes through Kaddish Shalem.

Comment: "Pesukei D'Zimra" means from Baruch Sheamar until Yishtabach. One should still respond "Amein" to the b'racha of Baruch Sheamar, and may even do so if you have already recited it and are in the middle of Pesukei D'Zimra when general interruptions are forbidden (although you may need to be between paragraphs). You may also respond "Y'hei Sh'lama Raba" to kaddish at this point.

Comment: Personally I progress Pesukei D'zimra at my own pace as if I slow down to keep up with the shaliach tzibbur early on, it might be that in the latter part he is going faster and I cannot keep up. Although in practice it is more commonly the other way round.