# Minhagim on where the Shatz Begins Shacharit

Tags: tefilla, minhag, tefillah-betzibbur

Different communities have different minhagim concerning where the shatz begins by Shacharit. Some communities begin with Birkat HaShachar and others Rabbi Yishmael, and still others by Hodu/Mizmor Shir.

Why is this so? What might be the reasons for these different minhagim?

Comment: Do you mean which parts are recited in unison? Something else? Consider clarifying.

Comment: AFAIK the Shatz doesn't start anywhere until (just before) the Kaddish after Yishtabach. Communal prayer has a leader for Shema and Shemoneh Esrei until Kaddish Titkabbel. That's it. related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56277/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55756/759 Having someone at the front announcing the beginnings and ends of paragraphs of customary psalms or torah study is just something people do if they want to keep pace with each other, but isn't a halachic part of communal prayer or of any fundamental significance.

Comment: @mevaqesh - I have edited to make the question make more sense.

Comment: @ezra please try to use less jargon and even get rid of some of the OP's if already editing